# add() argument after * must be a sequence, not Groups

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to pass a 'group' as an extra field using [importer-option](http://django-adaptors.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#importer-option) from [django-adaptors](http://django-adaptors.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#importer-option) but I'm getting the following error...

**add() argument after * must be a sequence, not Group**

```
ContactCSVModel.import_data(data=self.filepath, extra_fields="1")
```

This is my CsvModel...

**CsvModel.py**

```
class ContactCSVModel(CsvModel):

    first_name = CharField()
    last_name = CharField()
    company = CharField()
    mobile = CharField()
    groups = DjangoModelField(Group)

    class Meta:
        delimiter = "^"
        dbModel = Contact
        update = {
            'keys': ['mobile']
        }
```

**model.py**

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    """
    Stores all contacts.
    """
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    mobile = models.IntegerField(max_length=20)
    active = models.BooleanField(help_text="States if pet type is active/selectable.")
    modified = models.DateTimeField(null=True, auto_now=True, help_text="Shows when object was modified.")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, help_text="Shows when object was created.")

    #FK
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, related_name='contacts')
```

Looking at the project on git (below), could there be any issue with the project and many2many fields, maybe, if so how to fix? or is it my code?

https://github.com/anthony-tresontani/django-adaptors/blob/master/adaptor/model.py#L436

Comment: Could you post the whole traceback?

Comment: I can not make your example work, can you also post a sample of your CSV file ?

Comment: The issue could be the fact that its a ManyToManyField, I tried with a simple FK and this worked. Maybe a bug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment django-adaptors doesn't support ManyToManyFields. As there is more and more requests about it, I am going to integrate it soonish.

If you want to workaround that, you should work in 2 steps.
The first one would be to create a python object by using a simple CSVModel by removing:

```
dbModel = Contact
```

Unfortunately, you would also have to do the update logic manually.

Then you would need to explicitly create the django instance by doing something like:

```
contact = Contact.objects.create(first_name = csv_object.first_name, ....)
contact.groups.add(csv_object.group)
```

Hope that helps